# Git editing my files

Tags: windows, git, github

I just installed Git on my PC (Windows 8.1 Pro) and cloned my repository (containing about 5000 `.c` and `.h` files) from Github via `git clone`. Now if I say `git status`, it shows five modified files (the changes show some words replaced by others).

The problem is that I can't commit this; if I try `git add .` in my project's root directory, nothing happens. Running `git status` after still lists five files as modified. Running `git commit` doesn't remedy the situation.

I am running on the newest version of git on windows

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried `git add --all .`?  And don't forget to run `git commit` if you haven't.

Comment: Did the file modifications show up immediately after cloning or did you edit something? Your question makes it look like the former but I want to make sure.

Comment: @musiKk Immediately!

Comment: Could it be a problem with case sensitivity, i.e., two files with names that only differ in the case of some characters? I once helped someone with a very similar problem on a Mac (which also by default has a case insensitive file system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer..

I had to install cygwin with integrated git package and clone the repository with cygwin, then commit and work with cygwin. I can use windows editors to edit the files!